# Public IP allocated by carrier, but I cannot see it on my Android phone

Tags: android, ip-address, public, galaxy, samsung-mobile

Carrier: Fido in Canada. 
Phone: Samsung Galaxy S2
OS: Android 4.0.3

Fido has a service where they allocate a public IP address for some fees. I have paid the fees and apparently they have allocated my phone a public IP address. In normal circumstances, I should be able to see the IP address in my device settings (status information). But it shows IP address unavailable. Fido customer service is not able to help, saying that they only have instructions for the iPhone. For any other phone, I should contact the manufacturer.

Any idea how I could go about finding the public IP address that I am paying through my nose for?

Comment: This isn't necessarily a developer question but did you get the instructions for the iPhone, they could be insightful.

Comment: StackOverflow is for programming questions. This is not a programming question. Try http://android.stackexchange.com.

Answer (score 1):

On the device, go to http://www.whatsmyip.org/ . That website will tell you the IP address you show to the internet.